# How to run a collator node for a parachain in Docker?

Tags: parachain-collator, docker, test-network

I'm working through the [Acquire a testnet slot](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/acquire-a-testnet-slot/) tutorial and used the following command to spin up a collator node:

```
./target/release/parachain-template-node --collator \
  --chain raw-parachain-chainspec.json \
  --base-path /tmp/parachain/pubs-demo \
  --port 50333 \
  --ws-port 8855 \
  -- \
  --execution wasm \
  --chain rococo \
  --port 50343 \
  --ws-port 9988
```

Eventually, we want to run our testnet collators via DigitalOcean Droplets rather than our local machines. Are there any examples of how to run a testnet parachain collator node through Docker rather than executing this command directly?

Answer (score 2):

i went the same approach, small VMs with docker or podman installed then spin up the container using the docker-compose.

Additionally i have the full node that is reverse_proxied with TLS

Here is the i've been using this for our network. this is the contents of the docker-compose.yml.

Hope that helps

```yml
version: "3"
services:
    collator1:
      image: registry.gitlab.com/anagolay/anagolay/idiyanale:3861d9b3
      volumes:
        - ./data/collator1_data:/data
        - ./specs/rococo:/genesis
      networks:
        - caddy
        - idiyanale_rococo
      labels:
        caddy: "rococo.rpc.idiyanale.anagolay.io"
        caddy.reverse_proxy: "{{upstreams 9944}}"
      command: |
        --base-path /data
        --chain /genesis/idiyanale-parachain-raw-4222.json
        --force-authoring
        --name rococo-idiyanale-collator1
        --collator
        --prometheus-external
        --no-telemetry
        --enable-offchain-indexing true
        --port 30333 
        --rpc-port 9933 
        --ws-port 9944 
        --unsafe-ws-external 
        --unsafe-rpc-external 
        --rpc-cors all 
        --sync fast-unsafe
        -- 
        --chain rococo
        --sync fast-unsafe
      cpus: 0.5
networks:
  idiyanale_rococo: {}
  caddy:
    external: true
```

if you get confused by `caddy` network it's the external network that is connected to the container that issues the automatic TLS and does the fwd proxy.

Hope this helps